# Render page and pass parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three html pages.

- In the **first page**, I  view the list of data.
- In the **second page**, I view the data of a particular element of the list.
- In the **third page**, the user can edit data of a particular element of the list.

When the user submits the 'form', how can I redirect the user in the second page? I tried in this way:

```
render :action => "show_details",:id=>params[:id]
```

It  works. The link is correct. But the page is not opened if I do not refresh the page.

**UPDATE I**

I write my code in this action in the reports controller:

```
 def setFixed
    rs=Report.find(params[:id])
    rs.state ="1"
    rs.save
    render :action => "show_details",:id=>params[:id]
  end
```

**UPDATE II**
Reports controller code:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:index,:show,:show_details,:new]

  def stateDialog
    render :stateDialog, :current_state=>params[:current_state]
  end

  def setFixed
    rs=Report.find(params[:id])
    rs.state ="1"
    rs.save
    render :action=>"show_details",:id=>params[:id]
  end

  def setNotFixed
    rs=Report.find(params[:id])
    rs.state ="0"
    rs.save
    render :action=>"show_details",:id=>params[:id]
  end

  def edit
    @report=Report.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
      if @report.update_attributes(params[:report])
        flash[:notice]=''
        render :action=>"show_details",:id=>params[:id]
      else
        flash[:notice]=''
        render :action=>"show_details",:id=>params[:id]
      end
  end

  def deleteDialog
    render "deleteDialog"
  end

  def focus_maps
    render "focus_maps"
  end

  def delete
    Report.find(params[:id]).destroy
    render "show"
  end

  def index
    @report=Report.new
  end

  def logged
    render "new"
  end

  def show
    render params[:page]
  end

  def new
    @report=Report.new
  end

  def show_details
    render "show_details"
  end


  def create
    @report=Report.new( params[:report] )

    if @report.save
       flash[:notice]='Segnalazione avvenuta!'
    else
       flash[:notice]='Impossibile sottoporre la segnalazione!'
    end

    render "show"

  end
end
```

Comment: where have you written this code in controller or view?

Comment: can you show your controller code?

Comment: i write this code in controller, i update my post with major details.

Comment: want do you sees all controller code or only the action code?

Comment: and please show 'show_detail' action.

Comment: ok I updated my post with this information.

Comment: Now it work! But i don't understand what did i do. boo..

Answer (score 7):

I found advice that params must be filled before `render` calling, like this:

```
@id = params[:id]
render :action => 'show_details'
```

This solution is works for me, try it

Comment: yep, it doesn't make sense to talk about parameters since in this case we're just rendering a view, and not redirecting to an URL.

We could see it as a show action - set the instance variables and render the view

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect user somewhere you should use `redirect_to`

```
redirect_to action: 'show_details', id: params[:id]
```

Comment: i tried it! but there is the some problem... the link that i view in the browser is: http://127.0.0.1:3000/setFixed?id=1 but the screen is white and only after a refresh page i view the show_details page.